# Matplotlib style.use('tex') error in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, latex, tex

Firstly apologies for the similarity to other questions, but I believe this is a different issue from all the previous questions/answers I have found. Please refer me to other questions if you think I'm wrong, but please also read the full question to check I haven't already tried the solution provided in the other question.

I had a working setup using Conda and matplotlib to do data-processing and plot figure with latex formatted captions etc, due to some lingering issues I did a full clean install. Trying to recreate my environment from before produces this error, unsure exactly what version of Catalina I was running pre-reboot but the Big Sur version I'm now running is 11.2.1.

Code required to reproduce the issue (running in a miniconda environment, full package list at the end):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('tex')
```

I have confirmed the following:

- tex and latex are both installed and work, both are found by "which" and both run, version information:

  - tex: Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020)
  - latex: pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
- dvipng is installed and runs (v 1.17)
- Ghostscript is installed and runs (v 9.50)
- The above are all present in PATH, as well as os.environ['PATH']:

  - latex, tex, dvipng are in /Library/TeX/texbin/
  - gs is in /usr/local/bin

Full error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/style/core.py", line 121, in use
    rc = rc_params_from_file(style, use_default_template=False)
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 883, in rc_params_from_file
    config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error=fail_on_error)
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 812, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 790, in _open_file_or_url
    with open(fname, encoding=encoding) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tex'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/style/core.py", line 124, in use
    raise IOError(
OSError: 'tex' not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL or path; see `style.available` for list of available styles
```

Questions I have:

- How can I have the following sequence of outputs:

  - os.environ['PATH'] and sys.path both show '/Library/TeX/texbin'
  - os.path.isfile('/Library/TeX/texbin/tex') -> True
  - os.path.isfile('tex') -> False
- Why is Matplotlib trying to open the tex executable as if its a (utf-8) text file ?
- What other things should I try / verify ?

Thanks in advance !

Full Conda list output:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h033912b_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            h0ab9d94_1001    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py38h50d1736_1    conda-forge
curl                      7.71.1               hb0a8c7a_1
cycler                    0.10.0                   py38_0
fontconfig                2.13.1            hd23ceaa_1004    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               ha233b18_0
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h7937167_1005    conda-forge
glib                      2.67.4               hdf23fa2_1
gmp                       6.1.2             h0a44026_1000    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.13            h12caacf_1001    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hb8d4a28_0
icu                       58.2              h0a44026_1000    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py38h23ab428_0
krb5                      1.18.2               h75d18d8_0
lcms2                     2.11                 h92f6f08_0
libcurl                   7.71.1               h8a08a2b_1
libcxx                    10.0.0                        1
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h1de35cc_1
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2
libiconv                  1.16                 haf1e3a3_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0
libssh2                   1.9.0                h52ee1ee_6    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_1
libxml2                   2.9.10               h7cdb67c_3
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h23ab428_0
matplotlib                3.3.4            py38hecd8cb5_0
matplotlib-base           3.3.4            py38h8b3ea08_0
mkl                       2019.4                      233
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38h9ed2024_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py38ha059aab_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h959d312_0
mpfr                      4.0.2                h44b798e_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_1
numpy                     1.19.2           py38h456fd55_0
numpy-base                1.19.2           py38hcfb5961_0
olefile                   0.46                       py_0
openjpeg                  2.3.1                h254dc36_3    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1j               hbcf498f_0    conda-forge
ordered-set               4.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.2.3            py38hb2f4e1b_0
pcre                      8.44                 h4a8c4bd_0    conda-forge
pillow                    8.1.2            py38h5270095_0
pip                       21.0.1           py38hecd8cb5_0
pixman                    0.38.0            h01d97ff_1003    conda-forge
poppler                   0.81.0               h2ef9dbd_1
poppler-data              0.4.10                        0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python                    3.8.8                h88f2d9e_4
python-dateutil           2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.8                      1_cp38    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
readline                  8.1                  h9ed2024_0
scipy                     1.6.1            py38h2515648_0
seaborn                   0.11.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
setuptools                52.0.0           py38hecd8cb5_0
six                       1.15.0           py38hecd8cb5_0
sqlite                    3.33.0               hffcf06c_0
texlive-core              20180414             ha09c46f_0
tk                        8.6.10               hb0a8c7a_0
tornado                   6.1              py38h9ed2024_0
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
xz                        5.2.5                h1de35cc_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
zstd                      1.4.5                h41d2c2f_0
```

UPDATE:

Tried using

```
plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True})
```

And producing a simple plot, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 275, in _run_checked_subprocess
    report = subprocess.check_output(command,
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['latex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '--halt-on-error', '/Users/will_gerrard/.matplotlib/tex.cache/d2acc2706db635f7f7afe7dc80ac47f1.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Here is the full report generated by latex:

```
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/share/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/share/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/share/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/share/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/texmf/web2c.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=latex)

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/share/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/share/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/share/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/share/texmf/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/texmf-local/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/texmf-dist/web2c:/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/texmf/web2c.
/Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/mktexfmt: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/will_gerrard/opt/miniconda3/envs/plotting/bin/mktexfmt line 25.
I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to set a `tex` style? Or do you want to output tex?

Comment: Essentially all I want is to use latex for formatting all text in matplotlib. The way I did this before was with this line. As an alternative I can try just setting "text.usetex": True, this also produced an error, ill update the question